# ionic content scroll bouncing ONLY on ios and never on android

Tags: ionic-framework

"has-bouncing" is working on iOS but only when I manually set it:

```
<content has-bouncing="true">
    ...
</content>
```

The issue is that then it shows up on android too, which I do not want. I just want the page to scroll on each device as the users would expect for that OS.

How can I get the page to bounce on iOS and not-to-bounce on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first set a boolean that is true for iOS into your controller that has the content. 
This is available on the ionic standard package, no need to add other modules :
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

For example

```
If (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) $scope.hasbounce=true;
```

Then into your html template just paste your newly variable into

```
has-bounce="hasbounce"
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not wanting to work for me. My module setup currently is: `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])` so how can I go about adding `'PlatformApp'` ?